# HTML (Video Hover (Div)/Button)

Tags: html, css

Here is the working code for a video with a hovering button

```
<div class="video">
<iframe 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" onclick="playPause(this)" class="btn btn-primary">&#9646;&#9646</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="muteUnmute(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Mute</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="goHD(this)" class="btn btn-primary">HD</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.video {position: relative; width: 350px;}
.video img {display: block;}
.video .buttons {position: absolute; bottom: 30px; z-index: 0; width: 100%; text-align: left; 
  left: 10px;}
```

It works like it should, but I wanted to ask, how do I make it like "this site" where the button only shows when video is playing? + (the style)

> Site: https://www.rolex.com/

Answer (score 0):

your css is looking for an image where you have used an iFrame

try replace this line `.video iframe {display: block;}`

changing `img` to `iframe`